# How to specify aws region within boto program?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to list the `ec2` instances in aws account with boto module.I am getting the issue as

> "You must specify a region".Here is the program.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for instance in ec2.instances.all()
print instance.id, instance.state
```

I didn't specify any default region. How can I specify it programmatically                                                                                           ?

Comment: Create an client    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-2') and query the resources

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using the resource interface, your code will look like this:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'us-west-2')
for instance in ec2.instances.all()
    print instance.id, instance.state
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how your code would look like using client instead of resource

```
 import boto3
 ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-1')
 a = ec2.describe_instances()
 for i in a['Reservations']:
    for j in i['Instances']:
       print "state of the instance"+j['InstanceId']+" is:"+j['State']['Name']
```

This is just one of the methods.There are a lot more methods.Try it yourself